# How to populate a list inside a dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a dictionary that needs to be populated with a list. The code below does not work. How can I fix it?

clientinfo.cs

```
public Dictionary<int, List<string>> Languages { get; set; }
```

main.cs

```
var ClientsData = new List<MapModel.ClientInfo> { }
ClientsData.Add(new MapModel.ClientInfo { Id = IDCounterDoctors, Languages = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>()});
ClientsData[0].Languages.Add(2376, ["english", "french"]); // issue is here
```

Comment: have u initialized the Languages property? ClientsData[0].Languages = new Dictionary<int,List<string>>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialization of list is wrong. Also make sure your languages property is initialized

```
ClientsData[0].Languages = new Dictionary<int,List<string>>();
ClientsData[0].Languages.Add(2376,new List<string>(){ "english", "french"});
```

Answer (score 1):

your code has 2 mistakes:

1.var ClientsData = new List { }, here should be () not {};

2.ClientsData[0].Languages.Add(2376, ["english", "french"]); here should new a List object;

I edited your code, like this:

```
//initialize client data(list)
var ClientsData = new List<MapModel.ClientInfo>();
//add one ClientInfo into ClientData
ClientsData.Add(new MapModel.ClientInfo { Id = IDCounterDoctors,
                             Languages = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>()});
//set value to the first clientInfo's Language
ClientsData[0].Languages.Add(2376, new List<string>() { "english", "french" });
```